# Custom allocator, new/delete vs malloc()/free()

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

So, this question mainly arised thanks to posts like these:
[Why are new()/delete() slower than malloc()/free()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570552/why-are-new-delete-slower-than-malloc-free)

Consider yourself in a situation where:

- you mainly work with plain old data types, and you have to do a lot
  of allocations/deallocations
- you work with contiguous memory blocks
- for some reason, performance really, really matters...

The idea is, to come up with a new allocator class, which can "choose" between the two methods, namely `new` and `malloc()`. 
Let's say you will use `std::allocator` if your type **is not** a POD type,
 and use an allocator like this one, described here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator (Mallocator) 
 if your type **is** a POD type

And now, to select your allocator class, you will use something like this:

```
namespace meta
{

    template<bool, typename T>
    struct Allocator_Impl;

    template<typename T>
    struct Allocator_Impl<true, T>
    {
        using type = Mallocator<T>;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Allocator_Impl<false, T>
    {
        using type = std::allocator<T>;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct is_trivially_allocateable
    {
        using type = typename
        std::conjunction<std::is_trivial<T>,
                         std::is_standard_layout<T>>::type;

        constexpr static inline bool value = type::value;
    };
}

template<typename T>
struct Allocator : public meta::Allocator_Impl<meta::is_trivially_allocateable<T>::value, T>
{};
```

After this, to implement our "smart?" container we can simply inherit from the good old `vector` class, for example. Let's say this vector here is somewhere in another namespace, for example `sna`:

```
namespace sna
{
    template<typename T> using allocTy = typename Allocator<T>::type;


    template<typename T, class Alloc = allocTy<T>>
    class vector : public std::vector<T, Alloc>
    {
    public:
        typedef typename std::vector<T, Alloc>::size_type size_type;
        typedef T value_type;
        typedef Alloc allocator;
        typedef std::vector<value_type, allocator> parent;

        vector() : parent() {}
        vector(const size_type n) :
            parent(n)

        ... implement other constructors if needed ...
    };
}
```

After this - just to make sure - I, too, benchmarked the allocation times and came up with:

> Allocating 100000000 double:
>  
>   Duration with normal vector:    281528400 ns.
>   Duration with custom vector:    1990600 ns.

For the benchmark I used this piece of code:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point start, stop;

const size_t size = 100000000;
std::cout << "Allocating " << size << " doubles:" << std::endl;

start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::vector<double> new_data(size);
stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::cout << "Duration with normal vector: ";
std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(stop - start).count() << " ns." << std::endl;

start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
sna::vector<double> malloc_data(size);
stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::cout << "Duration with custom vector: ";
std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(stop - start).count() << " ns." << std::endl;
```

For this benchmark, I used the -O2 optimization flag.
So, for me the `vector` using the `Mallocator` class is more than a hundred times faster, than the one using the `std::allocator`, which in my opinion is a considerable performance gain.

But all that aside:
Is something like this "trick" considered a bad practice, or if the situation is as described above, can you use something like this safely? Would there be another better solution, or this would just not worth the effort and I should stick with the `std::vector` type instead?

Comment: Firstly, if performance really matters, memory allocation should not be in time-critical code at all.   Second, benchmarking that measures the time for a single allocation is not representative of much - benchmarking therefore usually forces some operation to be performed a large number of times, and computes the total or average over that large number of times.  Third, quite a few modern systems use lazy allocation - the memory is not actually allocated unless it is non-trivially used, so the times you are measuring may not include physical allocation of the memory.

Comment: I doubt with `-O2` it would even really create the `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that, to this end, I performed some 'dummy' calculations on the arrays. Given random values to each element and then summed them together element by element. To make sure they are really allocated.